# How can i add velocity plugin to ScrollMagic with npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

I need to add scrollMagic with velocity plugin to my npm library.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "library",
  "version": "1.0.10",
  "description": "blabla",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "shortid": "2.x",
    "jquery": "2.x",
    "scrollmagic": "2.x"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Simply adding ScrollMagic does not include plugins.

Please let me know if more info is needed.

EDIT:

If i add the plugin like this: require('scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.velocity.js')

I get these error.

```
    ERROR in ./~/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.velocity.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'ScrollMagic' in /home/av/local.dev/testest/node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins
 @ ./~/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.velocity.js 31:2-46

ERROR in ./~/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.velocity.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'velocity' in /home/av/local.dev/testest/node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins
 @ ./~/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.velocity.js 31:2-46
```

Comment: [It's in there](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/blob/master/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.velocity.js), you just have to use it. `require('scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins.animation.velocity.js')`

Comment: where do i put this? im my entry.js?

Comment: Probably. I don't know how your application is structured. Just include it after you've included ScrollMagic.

Comment: I edited the post and added the error that throws webpack when compiling  the plugin.

Comment: havin same issue. using browsify-rails. webpack doesnt fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've added these libraries to fix this in webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.json'],
        root: [Path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")],
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        alias: {
            "ScrollMagic": Path.resolve('node_modules', 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/minified/ScrollMagic.min.js'),
            "animation.velocity": Path.resolve('node_modules', 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/minified/plugins/animation.velocity.min.js'),
            "velocity": Path.resolve('node_modules', 'velocity-animate/velocity.min.js')
        }
    }
```